# Equivalent to Java's System.currentTimeMillis() in .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a .NET  equivalent to  Java's [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)?

I want to find the number of milliseconds since 1970.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Dim epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    Dim millis = CLng((DateTime.UtcNow - epoch).TotalMilliseconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
(DateTime.Now - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: @Michael ah, I was confusing `TimeSpan` and `DateTime`.  Corrected

Comment: Surely that is dependent on british summer time?

Comment: @jgubby it depends. I'm not an expert on time zones by any means.  If it's an issue though you should consider the UTC versions

Comment: I don't know - it just needs to be 100% identical to System.currentTimeMillis() in Java - i.e no time zones.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function

```
(DateTime.UtcNow- New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds
```

will generate the exact value as `System.CurrentMillis()` in Java

Thanks for the answer of JaredPar